# "ImportError: No module named gtk" although it is installed

Tags: python, debian, pygtk

The following code fails although I have the gtk bindings for python installed. This is a debian machine and I have the package named python-gtk2 installed

```
>>> import gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gtk
```

How can I fix this?

Edit1: Per comment request: Python 2.7.3rc2 (default, May 22 2012, 01:05:47)

Edit2: Per comment request:

```
>>> print sys.path
['', '/home/lorb', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SpssClient200', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spss200']
```

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: `import sys; print sys.path` - is it on the path?

Comment: @Simeon: In what path should gtk be?

Comment: It doesn't really matter (other than for convention's sake) as long as gtk is in a directory on your Python path.  Is it in one of the directories listed by sys.path?  It would most likely be in either dist-packages or site-packages.

Comment: How do I know where gtk is? I installed it via aptitude

Comment: Try `dpkg -L python-gtk2`

Comment: Tells me /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/ which is on the path

Answer (score 0):

Do this if you are using something other than Ubuntu 20:

```
sudo apt install python-gtk2 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

And do this if you are using Ubuntu 20:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb && sudo apt install --fix-broken && sudo dpkg -i python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Does Ubuntu 20.04 not provide any packages for pygtk anymore?

Comment: At the time of writing this answer , yes its not provided